# Unable to connect remotely to SQL Azure DB using SSMS 2016

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-azure-federations

I am able to connect to SQL Azure database using sql authentication . However, I am unable to connect using domain account(domain\AccountName) from Azure VM. I am using SSMS 2016 version and using the option 'Active Directory Integrated' and default database as the azure database.

Few things to keep in mind
1) I have created this Azure database in portal using the same account that I am testing now to connect from Azure VM.
2)This domain account has MFA enabled because while connecting to VPN , I need to enter the password that I get over my phone to login

Below are the errors that I am getting when trying to use each of the options

1) Active Directory Integrated

> Cannot connect to XXXXX.database.windows.net.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Failed to authenticate the user NT Authority\Anonymous Logon in Active
>   Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated). Error code
>   0xCAA2000C; state 10 AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made
>   by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you
>   must use multi-factor authentication to access xxxxx. Trace ID:
>   06d7d4bc-4fc2-4ce3-9bda-486e31370300 Correlation ID:
>   ac7592ee-1c21-4875-8455-5a10a9588725 Timestamp: 2018-08-09 06:14:07Z
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)

2) Active Directory Password

> Cannot connect to xxx.database.windows.net.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Failed to authenticate the user User@domainname in Active
>   Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword). Error code
>   0xCAA2000C; state 10 AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made
>   by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you
>   must use multi-factor authentication to access
>   xxxx. Trace ID:
>   ac6347b5-c1f8-4f81-8f83-5284b8010400 Correlation ID:
>   4e67f279-1d47-4ce9-97d7-68e074f616fc Timestamp: 2018-08-09 07:22:40Z
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)

3)Active Directory MFA

> Cannot connect to xxx.database.windows.net.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> One or more errors occurred. (mscorlib)
>
> ---
>
> Unable to acquire authorization token
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AzureAuthenticationManagement)
>
> ---
>
> One or more errors occurred. (mscorlib)
>
> ---
>
> User canceled authentication
>   (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory)

Answer (score 0):

You are able to connect from an Azure VM because is a trusted location for Azure. You need to create a trusted location with the IP address where you are running SSMS. Please follow instructions on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/location-condition) article.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hv deleted the temporary files and its working fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).